# Find minimum value of this integral expression.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let f be a continuously differentiable real-valued function on [0,1] such that 
$\int_{1/3}^{2/3} f(x)dx = 0$. Find the minimum value of  $$I = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}f′(x)^2 dx} {(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx)^2}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: first of all I tried to differentiate but it was too complex. My approach was to differentiate and double differentiate and then find min value according to sign of double differentiable value.